# SSH login mac-to-mac

Tags: macos, ssh

I have an iMac that I use somewhat as a server, and a Macbook laptop.  For months I've opened a terminal on my laptop, typed "ssh user@host" (with more useful choices for 'user' and 'host', and was promptly rewarded with a "Password:" prompt, then the normal '$' prompt.  Today it doesn't give me the $ prompt aftr a correct password.  As a test, I gave an invalid pssword, and was rewarded with another prompt for password.  The final test was to open the Terminus app  on my iPhone, and got immediately to the $ prompt.

What might be the problem here, and where do I look first for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is:

```
ssh -v user@host
```

to get verbose messages.

If you have recently upgraded the server to macOS Ventura and you used to use RSA keys, you will probably need to log into the server and edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and add the following two lines at the end since Apple tightened up security to disallow that older, relatively less secure method:

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Thanks.  The messages were, indeed, verbose.   If you want to see them let me know.  basically trying different authentication methods  and landing on "keyboard-interactive" before issuing the Password:  prompt.  I can succed by logging into my Raspberry Pi, then ssh-ing into my iMac.  My laptop is on Ventura 13.1.  Adding those two lines didn't change any behavior.  Thanks for the attention.  One more thing-- After entering my password, Ctl-C  does not terminate the ssh command.  I have to open another Terminal window and kill it.

Comment: I have no idea what happened overnight, but it's back to normal today.  Sigh.